# set_post_thumbnail_size in percent, not pixels?

Tags: custom-post-types, images, post-thumbnails

I've created a new custom post type and I need the post thumbnails or featured images generated by the `get_the_post_thumbnail()` function to be set in percent, rather than pixels, as I'm using a fluid grid. Ideally I would only set the width (to 100%). Is there a way to do this? Potentially using `add_image_size()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

have you tried,

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {                    
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),'full' );
     echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="100%"  />';
}
```

Comment: Smart +1. Should be plugin ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the units of the default width and height output, but you can possibly override the output via css:

```
/* these are the classes that get added per default */
img.wp-post-image
img.attachment-thumbnail
img.attachment-medium
img.attachment-large
img.attachment-full
```

Then you can override it via something like `body img.attachment-large { width: 50% !important; height: 50% !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that issue getting rid of all width and height attributes set by WP:

```
    //tidy up img tags. We don't want inline height and width added by WP.
    //we'd rather use media queries and fluid img.
        function remove_image_dim_attr($html) {
            $html=preg_replace( '/width=(["\'])(.*?)\1/', '', $html );
            $html=preg_replace( '/height=(["\'])(.*?)\1/', '', $html );
            return $html;
        }
        add_filter( 'get_image_tag','remove_image_dim_attr' );
        add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor','remove_image_dim_attr' );
        add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html','remove_image_dim_attr' );
```